# How to write a value in one cell if another cell equals X with multiple variations

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to place a value in column B depending on the value in column A e.g. If the value in column A = Hat then the value in B would = Clothes, if it is Cat then the value would = Animal.

Comment: Use a ***VLOOKUP()*** table

Comment: If the answer works as you mentioned, please, accept it

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a table first with all the references and then use VLOOKUP() formula to search through the reference table and provide the result. See Screenshot:

[image: Example]

Cell A2 has the data you're looking for. Cell B2 provides the result with the following formula:

```
=+VLOOKUP(A2,D2:E7,2,FALSE)
```

Table in columns D:E is the reference where the search is done.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted. How would I make the VLOOKUP table reference a different sheet (e.g. sheet name VLOOKUP)? I've tried to use Sheet! argument but can't make it work.

Comment: I figured it out! =+VLOOKUP(A2,VLOOKUP!A2:B8,2,FALSE) Thanks a lot for your help